# Spring Web App + JPA No transactional EntityManager available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've gone through a lot of similar question on SO, generally the answer is to just add `@Transactional` to the class(es) and method(s).  But this is not working for me, thus I assume I'm doing something else wrong?

**MyRepository:**

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository extends AbstractRepository<MyEntity> implements org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public MyRepository() {
        super(MyEnitiy.class);
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<MyEnitiy> getAllFor(Integer id) {        
        return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT k FROM MyEntity k WHERE k.otherid = :otherid ORDER BY k.something", MyEntity.class)
            .setParameter("otherid", id).getResultList();
    }
}
```

**AbstractRepository:**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public abstract class AbstractRepository<T> {

    ...
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }
    ...
}
```

**My Sping web controller (Snippet):**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/here/there"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public String hereAndTherePage(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Integer id,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        List<MyEntity> myEntities = myRepository.getAllFor(id);
        for(MyEntity myEntity : myEntities) {
            ...
            myEntity.setSomeValue(myEntity.getSomeValue() + 1);
            ...
            myRepository.edit(myEntity);
```

**Update:**

spring-database.xml (the use of a pool was an attempt to try and fix a Tomcat memory leak):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="poolProperties" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bfwinkel?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true"/> 
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="jdbcInterceptors" value="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    <property name="username" value="d[-.-]b"/>
    <property name="password" value="~!~"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="poolProperties" ref="poolProperties"/>
</bean>
```

**The exception** is thrown when `getEntityManager().merge(entity);` is called:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
```

Comment: Have you defined `EntityManager` bean?

Comment: Please post your spring xml with entity manager bean and transaction manager bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below lines to your spring-database.xml

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Comment: Below is the example code                                                http://tarunjain-jaintarun.blogspot.de/2016/06/csv-reader-and-jpa-example.html

Answer (score 0):

This error means that, they are no available persistence context available when you try to merge your entity.

You have Three options to fix this issue by priority.

1- Have you added @EnableTransactionManagement to your configuration ?

2- If you have a persistence.xml file, you should add a unitname attribute to @PersistenceContext.

3- Use Extended Persistence context instead of  Transaction-scoped Persistence context.

I hope my answer will help you.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have a persistence.xml file but if I get bean doesn't exist when I put unitName at @PersistenceContext - something I still need to invstigate.

Comment: Any news ? Do you fix your problem ?

Comment: not yet but it seems to work for me (with no unitName)